# How to exit calling method without throwing exception?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a cleaner way of handling guard clauses in C#? My code with guard clauses and multiple repository calls to load data to process:

```
public Result Method1(string id)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
        return ArgumentError(nameof(id));

    var dto1 = _repository1.Get(id);
    if (dto1 == null)
        return NotFoundError();

    var dto2 = _repository2.Get(dto1.Dto2Id);
    if (dto2 == null)
        return NotFoundError();

    var dto3 = _repository3.Get(dto2.Dto3Id);
    if (dto3 == null)
        return NotFoundError();

    Handle(dto3);
}
```

I'm not using exceptions. Results will be handled in a Webpipeline filter to be mapped to a HTTP response code. Response should always be a NotFoundError. I could refactor:

```
public Result Method1(string id)
{
    var guardResult = Guard(id);
    if (guardResult.IsFailed)
        return guardResult;

    var dto3 = LoadDto3(id);
    if (dto3 == null)
        return NotFoundError();

    Handle(dto3);
}
```

But that are still 3 lines for validation if I have to exit `Method1()`. How (besides an exception) could I exit `Method1()` from the method `Guard()`, something like:

```
public Result Method1(string id)
{
    Guard(id);
    var dto3 = LoadDto3(id);
    Handle(dto3);
}
```

so `Guard(id)` or `LoadDto3(id)` directly exit `Method1()` if they produced an error? In the public method I want only method calls so the workflow even one from business could understand.

Comment: I think you might be discovering one of the reasons why exceptions are designed the way they are. Next you'll be asking "Is there a way of forcing people to check `guardResult.IsFailed`, rather than accidentally ignoring it"...

Comment: @canton7 Actually there is : [OneOf](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf)

Comment: @Irwene I might have missed an edit, but I don't quite understand the relevance of discriminated unions here?

Comment: @Irwene Only if someone does e.g. `return guardResult.Match(...)`. There's nothing in C# which prevents people from discarding results, e.g. Rust's `#[must_use]`

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama This version of error-handling is used by some languages which don't have exceptions. By and large, those use a `Result` type which is a DU

Comment: Allowing for a method to control the flow of *calling code* sounds like a recipe for very strange bugs.

Comment: I agree that it's close to a "Failed" or "Result", but that doesn't seem to be what OP wants given their additional guard statement separate to the rest. That's why I don't see it as useful (in this specific situation).

Comment: Didn't  see the last code block, and yeah, for that last one, OneOf won't help, but unless one wants to play *really* dirty, it's just not possible without exceptions

Comment: The only supported mechanism for _enforced early exit_ is an exception. In all other cases you need at least the three mentioned lines somewhere in code.

Comment: Sorry, I was not able to answer earlier: I think that you are right and especially answer of @David seems to answer this for me in a "never ever do this" manner. With this answer, GOTO statements come in my mind :)

Thank you for all your answers and I think that either Exceptions will be the way - or I will have to live with the 3 lines each time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, some kind of custom attributes for Your methods/classes would fit?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/attributes/writing-custom-attributes

I'm using something like that to check if service is configured to be working

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class FooAuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IActionFilter
{
    public static readonly bool IsFooAvaible = SettingsHelper.GetAppSettings().GetValue("FooAvaliable", false);
    public AuthorizeAttribute()
    {
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {

    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!IsFooAvaible)
            context.Result = new NotFoundResult(); 
    }
}
```

You can apply it to the whole class (For example, controller):

```
[FooAuthorize]
public class FooController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IFooService _service;
    public FooController(IFooService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
// Something else
}
```

Or only few methods:

```
public class FooController : BaseController
{
    private readonly IFooService _service;
    public FooController(IFooService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [FooAuthorize]
    public IActionResult DoSmth(SmthCommand command)
    {
        _service.DoSmth(command);

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).